# Можно ли упростить html?

Tags: html, php

У меня есть часто повторяющийся код html. Можно ли как то упростить это с помощью PHP переменных? Или как то еще.

```
<tr><td height="20" class="g1"><div class="m1">РАЗДЕЛ1</div></td></tr>
<tr><td width="160"><a target="_top" href="/pages1.php">Страница1</a></td></tr>
<tr><td width="160"><a target="_top" href="/pages2.php">Страница2</a></td></tr>
<tr><td width="160"><a target="_top" href="/pages3.php">Страница3</a></td></tr>
<tr><td width="160"><a target="_top" href="/pages4.php">Страница4</a></td></tr>
<tr><td width="160"><a target="_top" href="/pages5.php">Страница5</a></td></tr>
<tr><td width="160"><a target="_top" href="/pages6.php">Страница6</a></td></tr>
<tr><td width="160"><a target="_top" href="/pages7.php">Страница7</a></td></tr>
<tr><td width="160"><a target="_top" href="/pages8.php">Страница8</a></td></tr>
```

Имеется одинаковый код - повторяющийся.

```
<tr><td width="160"><a target="_top" href="/
```

Как можно улучшить это?
Спасибо.

Comment: Непаханое поле для работы ;)
Как вы хотите это оптимизировать, уменьшить код, или сгенерировать все таки?

Comment: Сгенерировать не получится просто. Дело в том, что есть еще разделы, в каждом разделе разное количество страниц. Я думал сгенерировать, но пока это слишком сложно, но можно.
Для начала уменьшить код.
Потом попробую сгенерировать - если получится :)

Comment: <tr><td><a href="/pages1.php">Страница1</a></td></tr>
Меньше этого ужать не выйдет, то что удалено - выносится в стили.

Есть еще вариант ссылку генерить из JS, тогда  будет так:
    <tr><td>Страница1</td></tr>
Ссылка будет неиндексируемой.

И последний вариант на ходу генерить таблицу через JS код.
Тогда кода как такового вообще не будет изначально и он сгенериться тот же самый на лету, но сгенерится. Тут все зависит тогда от вашего желания разобраться в каком-нибудь jQuery или Moo.

Comment: Так не проще будет. Я думал использовать переменные PHP, для повторяющегося кода html, а для ссылки и названия страницы использовать массив. Но у меня что то не получилось.
Этот файл называется menu.php, создал для него config.php и загрузил переменные, но почему то выдает ошибку синтаксическую на строку

   include './config.php';

Comment: Вот по колдовал и получил такой код:

    $k=0;
    $i=0;
    $n = 'null'; 
    while ($A[$k][$i] != $n):
      {
        while ($A[$k][$i] != $n):
        echo $A[$k][$i];
        $i++; endwhile; }
    $k++; $i = 0; endwhile;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть строка на PHP:
    <tr><td width="160"><a target="_top" href="/pages1.php">Страница1</a></td></tr>
Вместо меняющихся элементов вставляем Метки, я придумал такие {% a %}:

```
<tr><td width="160"><a target="_top" href="/pages{% a %}.php">Страница{% a %}</a></td></tr>
```

Далее сколько тебе надо их вывести ? 100 ? Пишем цикл.. 1..100

```
for ($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
```

А вместо меток вставляем переменную $i

```
for ($i=1;$i<=100;$i++)
  echo '<tr><td width="160"><a target="_top" href="/pages'.$i.'.php">Страница'.$i.'</a></td></tr>';
```

вот и все. Теперь для остальных разделов аналогично. Я написал много лишнего и повторил кое-что, просто для понимания может лучше будет.

Answer (score 3):

Если это `php` шаблон - примерно так:

```
<?for($i=1;$i<=8;++$i):?>
   <tr>
     <td width="160">
      <a target="_top" href="/pages<?=$i?>.php">
         Страница<?=$i?>
      </a>
     </td>
   </tr>
<?endfor?>
```

Comment: А если еще строку переменную впихнуть, типа
    $str = '<tr><td width="160"><a target="_top" href="/'; 

Не проще будет?

Comment: Я считаю что, все, что можно вывести без php - надо выводить без него, собственно именно поэтому ответ выглядит именно так...

Comment: Я плохо не знаком с другими языками, начинаю изучать PHP, и естественно сайт написанный на HTML переписываю на PHP. Задумака была такая, в файле menu.php создать циклы с использованием масивов, а в cofig.php ввести все переменные с html кодом и масивы, куда бы записывалось меню. Например для первого раздела использовать массив

    <?php
    // Многомерный массив
     $A["menu"] = array("razd"=>"машины", "0"=>"стр1"
                                          "1"=>"стр2"
                                          "8"=>"null");
?>

и т.д.

Comment: Это не многомерный массив.

Comment: должна быть еще колонка с названием файлов - по символам не уложился.

Comment: тогда лучше xml и парсер + "поля" сортировки, либо что-то эдакое

Comment: Это неплохая идея - не подумал. Спасибо.

Comment: ИМХО - шаблонизаторы рулят :) smarty форева.

Comment: ИМХО смарти маст дай ;D

Comment: @AlexWindHope обоснуйте[[